# Why are the effects from this command made potion not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In this command, the speed effect, strength, haste, health boost, absorption, jump boost, resistance and haste aren't working. Here is the command:

```
/give @p potion 1 8193 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:1,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:3,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:5,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:6,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:8,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:10,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:11,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:12,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:13,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:14,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:16,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:21,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:22,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980},{Id:23,Amplifier:255,Duration:19999980}],display:{Name:"Potion of Unlimited Power",Lore:["~CAUTION~ Very dangerous. Use with care.","Keep away from children."]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Amplifier` tag is stored to and read from NBT as a byte, with a range of -128 to 127. By setting the value outside this range, it's going to overflow to a different value. In this case, the value becomes -1. Certain effects will do the opposite or have no function if a negative amplifier is used.

You should stay within the -128 to 127 range:

```
/give @p potion 1 8193 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:1,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:3,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:5,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:6,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:8,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:10,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:11,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:12,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:13,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:14,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:16,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:21,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:22,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980},{Id:23,Amplifier:127,Duration:19999980}],display:{Name:"Potion of Unlimited Power",Lore:["~CAUTION~ Very dangerous. Use with care.","Keep away from children."]}}
```

---

The `/effect` command is able to use an amplifier higher than 127 because it's directly setting the *internal* amplifier, which is stored as an integer rather than a byte. But if the player leaves the game, that internal amplifier will be saved to NBT as a byte, overflowing to a proper value.